# Is $UP\not=NP$ with respect to random oracle?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, oracles, polynomial-hierarchy, random-oracles

It is shown in [An average-case depth hierarchy theorem for Boolean circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03398) a random oracle makes $PH$ infinite.

> Is it possible to also show $UP\not=NP\not=\Sigma_2^P\not=\Sigma_3^P\not=\Sigma_4^P\not=\dots\not=PH\not=PSPACE$ with respect to a random oracle or does a random oracle give $UP=NP$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Beigel CCC '89 showed $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{UP} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ with probability 1. Combined with Rossman-Servedio-Tan, this gives the result you want. You should always try the [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up) for questions like this...